# I want a chart whose label is x-axis and y-axis are string

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart, timeline, anychart

In this chart, we have several supporters, for example, the name here is brandy.
And a number of projects are marked on the X-axis.
And on the Y axis, the date that this supporter has the project.
For example, here the Brandly has TripTone360 from 2020 to 2022 and Trip from 2023 to 2025.
X-axis is for time range
What chart should I use for this issue?
And tell me how to change the format of the label, please.

I want something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/Shestac92/472b9512eabc07ff9864c1a90b02f0a7) describes how to achieve that using the AnyChart Android native library.

The result is below
[image]

Comment: and I want different       Line series1 = cartesian.line(series1Mapping);   But its number is not known and it changes how can I solve this?

Comment: and its not support                                                                                    
        ("2020/05/23", "TripTone3)
("2025/05/23", "TripTone3)
("2020/05/23", "Trip");
("2025/05/23", "Trip");          The pairs line up and overlap. If they must have different y

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you well. Please, mail us at support@anychart.com and provide all the requirements.